# How to update your website without destroying seo?

Tags: html, seo

I'm just talking about a normal update to your website (adding content, etc).

I was thinking i would just copy/paste all of the new files (css, html, javascript etc) into the public_html of my website, and this would mean i would replace all files even the ones that don't have any changes to them.

Would this be bad for seo, and if it is, what would be the best way to proceed? Should i only replace html files that have been updated/changed?

Thanks alot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is not a definitively answerable topic, it's ever changing guesstimation.

Answer (score 1):

Just overwriting files that have not changed will not have any effect on SEO - what may affect it is if page content / urls have changed.